# Double possessive with "that"

Tags: possessives

Is the usage of the 's in the following sentence valid English?

> His mind is that of a child's.

This looks like a double possessive to me, but having read the relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive#Double_genitive), I can't tell whether it's valid.

Comment: Yes, it does look that way, but it's idiomatic. In this context, if it helps, read *that of* in the sense of the comparative *like* - "His mind is *like* a child's (mind)", i.e. inquisitive, innocent, etc.

Comment: 'The handwriting was large and scrawly, like that of a child's.' is a non-metaphorical example from [_Her Father's Sins_
by Josephine Cox](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zx58jxOmreYC&pg=PT87&lpg=PT87&dq=%22like+that+of+a+child%27s%22&source=bl&ots=_nKv6Tb3Hc&sig=BnNip1qqjDymlU7NDqHP8ncaWLI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx8JvwvLnOAhXmLcAKHUzeA4wQ6AEIKTAD#v=onepage&q=%22like%20that%20of%20a%20child's%22&f=false). '... she had a zest for life like that of a child.' (The Mitts Paragon: The Life and Times of the Mitts Family) shows that the double possessive isn't always used.